# installing phpbb on tomcat issues

Tags: tomcat, phpbb

I'm trying to set up phpbb (and a few other) forum software webapps in Tomcat, and I'm having a weird problem with it.

Normally, I install webapps through the tomcat manager app, as .war files.

phpBB (and the other forum apps I've found) aren't war files though, they are just directories full of files.  Ok, so I follow the instructions to copy the files to a "phpBB3" directory in the tomcat/webapps directory.  Then I go to the tomcat manager, and see that it does in fact recognize the phpbb3 webapp and says it is running. Great!

But, when I actually go to https://xxxxxxxxx.com:8443/phpBB3/ like the instructions say, I just get the "HTTP 404 resource not available" message.  I get the same thing on all the forum apps I install this way ... so I'm thinking that I'm missing some crucial step somewhere?

(I did follow some steps a while back to enable PHP on all tomcat webapps, and I'm pretty sure that's working, as my other webapps use php fine)